# Rails 4 OR query with join table using group and having

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have a Rails 4 query like this:

```
user.positions.where('positions.active = ? OR positions.deadline < ?', false, Date.current).joins(:cvs).where(cvs: {accepted: true}).group(:id).having('COUNT(cvs.id) = 3')
```

This now produces the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `positions`.* FROM `positions` INNER JOIN `cvs` ON `cvs`.`position_id` = `positions`.`id` WHERE `positions`.`user_id` = 4 AND (positions.active = 0 OR positions.deadline < '2015-01-21') AND `cvs`.`accepted` = 1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(cvs.id) = 3
```

What I actually need is to make the second where query an OR condition, but the query from above results in an AND condition.

I also tried the following:

```
user.positions.joins(:cvs).where('positions.active = ? OR positions.deadline < ? OR cvs.accepted = 1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(cvs.id) = ?', false, Date.current, 3)
```

but this is converted by Rails to

```
SELECT  `positions`.* FROM `positions` INNER JOIN `cvs` ON `cvs`.`position_id` = `positions`.`id` WHERE `positions`.`user_id` = 4 AND (positions.active = 0 OR positions.deadline < '2015-01-21' OR cvs.accepted = 1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(cvs.id) = 3)
```

which throws an sql syntax error due to the closing parenthesis at the end. Without the opening and closing parenthesis or if putting the closing parenthesis after '2015-01-21' it would work. But I don't know how to tell Rails not to put any parenthesis there.

(What I actually want to query are all positions which are not active OR where deadline has already reached OR where a position has 3 accepted CV's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord cannot do `or` but Arel can. The amazing [scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/) will solve your problem:

```
Position.select(Position.arel_table[Arel.star]).where(
  Position.arel_table[:user_id].eq(4).or(
    Position.arel_table[:active].eq(0).or(Position.arel_table[:deadline].lt('2015-01-21')).or(Cv.arel_table[:accepted].eq(1))
  )
).joins(
  Position.arel_table.join(Cv.arel_table).on(
    Cv.arel_table[:position_id].eq(Position.arel_table[:id])
  ).join_sources
).group(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. scuttle.io seems to be a cool tool, but the query it generates doesn't consider the 'having count(cvs.id) = 3'. Also Position.arel_table[:user_id].eq(4) isn't really working as the query also returns positions of other users.

Comment: Here's the syntax for `having`. https://github.com/rails/arel#more-sophisticated-queries I would suggest filing a bug with the scuttle author as he's been very responsive.